# End the observing of Firebase swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my code when you do a refresh on the blog. I set it so the refresh animation lasts for two seconds and then it ends. When the user has no internet connection and they reload multiple times. The posts load twice or as many times they reload because Xcode is still observing the single event. How can I end observingSingleEvent if you cant get the data. Thank you.

```
@objc func handleRefresh() {
        print("Refresh!")

        toggleSeeNewPostsButton(hidden: true)
        countss = 2
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.countdownDisplayText), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        newPostsQuery.queryLimited(toFirst: 20).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            var tempPosts = [Post]()

            let firstPost = self.posts.first
            for child in snapshot.children {
                if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
                    let data = childSnapshot.value as? [String:Any],
                    let post = Post.parse(childSnapshot.key, data),
                    childSnapshot.key != firstPost?.id {

                    tempPosts.insert(post, at: 0)
                }
            }

            self.posts.insert(contentsOf: tempPosts, at: 0)
            print("here it is")
            let newIndexPaths = (0..<tempPosts.count).map { i in
                return IndexPath(row: i, section: 1)
            }

            self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: newIndexPaths, with: .top)
            self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)


            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something called Reachability to detect whether or not the user will ever get a connection.

In appDelegate:

```
var reachability: Reachability!
```

In AppDelegate, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
do {
try reachability = Reachability()
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.reachabilityChanged(_:)), name: Notification.Name.reachabilityChanged, object: reachability)
try reachability.startNotifier()
} catch {
     print(“This is not working.”)
}
```

Then in your actual viewController add this code to run the method:

```
@objc func reachabilityChanged(_ note: NSNotification) {
let reachability = note.object as! Reachability
if reachability.connection != .unavailable {
if reachability.connection == .wifi {
print(“Reachable via WiFi”)
} else {
print(“Reachable via Cellular”)
}
} else {

// This is where you would stop your spinner.
print(“Not reachable”)
}
}
```

Comment: ok thats great. Thank you I will use that as well. i just have my initial question if you can stop observing from firebase?

Comment: I don't believe so, just because the issue is local.